# Регистрация + авторизация и дальнейшее окно для авторизированных пользователей, как?

Tags: php, авторизация, регистрация

Cуществуют готовые шаблоны? Или придется всё писать самому?

Comment: Слишком всеобъемлющий вопрос и вы это понимаете. Отредактируйте, сконцентрируйтесь на конкретной детали.

Comment: Вопросы опросники запрещены в сообществе. Для повторного открытия, перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь репозиторием github.com для проектов с открытым исходным кодом. Вы обязательно найдете то, что вам нужно!

Готовая форма регистрации, авторизации и восстановления пароля
https://github.com/simfatic/RegistrationForm